# How to convert a hexadecimal string to long in c++

Tags: c++

I have a string which is as shown below.
std::string myString = "0005105C9A84BE03";

I want the exact data to be saved on some integer say "long long int"
long long int myVar = 0005105C9A84BE03;

When i print myVar i'm expecting output 1425364798979587.

I tried to use atoi, strtol stroi, strtoll but nothing worked out for me.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Please show how you used `strtoll` and the output you got. (The other ones can't possibly work since they convert to narrower types than `long long`.)

Comment: 1425364798979587 is the decimal value of 0005105C9A84BE03. Your variable is correct but the default base is decimal.

Comment: Show your failing code.

Comment: std::string myString = "0005105C9A84BE03";
long long int var1 = strtol(myString.c_str(), NULL, 0);

Comment: Please edit your question to show that you did already some tries. Answering with comments is not the best idea ;) As you can see in my answers, the failure was that base ( last parameter of the function ) must be set to 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string hexValue = "0005105C9A84BE03"; // Original string

    std::istringstream converter { hexValue }; // Or ( ) for Pre-C++11

    long long int value = 0; // Variable to hold the new value

    converter >> std::hex >> value; // Extract the hex value

    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

This code uses an `std::istringstream` to convert from `std::string` to `long long int`, through the usage of the [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) stream manipulator.

[Example](https://repl.it/repls/LustrousAttachedSpringpeeper)

Comment: It worked for me, you need to change { hexValue} to (hexValue)

Comment: @RandomGuy No, {} is correct. Your question is tagged c++ and that means in 2018 that c++11 is in place! Please do not use c++03 syntax any longer! We have 2018!

Comment: While Klaus is correct, I will add a comment for clarity @RandomGuy

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of functions to convert from string to different integer types like:

> stol    Convert string to long int (function template )
>
> stoul   Convert string to unsigned integer (function template )
>
> strtol  Convert string to long integer (function )

They are some more. Please take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoul At the end of the documentation you find alternative functions for different data types.

All they have a "base" parameter. To convert from hex simply set `base=16`.

```
std::cout << std::stoul ("0005105C9A84BE03", 0, 16) << std::endl;
```